# Audio streaming with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, activex

Is there any way with vb.net of accomblishing MMS audio streaming?

Also, i read somewhere else within SO, that MMS streaming is no more supported by Microsoft. Is that true? Just curious..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I dug from Googling. Wikipedia:[Microsoft Media Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server) says:

> Microsoft Media Server (MMS) is the
>   name of Microsoft's proprietary
>   network streaming protocol used to
>   transfer unicast data in Windows Media
>   Services (previously called NetShow
>   Services). MMS can be transported via
>   UDP or TCP. The MMS default port is
>   UDP/TCP 1755.
>
> Microsoft deprecated MMS in favor of
>   [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) (TCP/UDP port 554) in 2003 with
>   the release of the Windows Media
>   Services 9 Series, but continued to
>   support the MMS for some time in the
>   interest of backwards compatibility.
>   Support for the protocol was finally
>   dropped in Windows Media Services
>   2008.

The spec for [Microsoft Media Server (MMS) Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc234711%28PROT.10%29.aspx) is public since 2008 by Microsoft:

> The client can send MMS Protocol
>   request messages to the server over
>   the TCP connection, requesting the
>   server to perform actions such as
>   starting and stopping the flow of
>   multimedia data. The multimedia data
>   is transferred either over the same
>   TCP connection or as a flow of UDP
>   packets.

w:[VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player#Output_formats_for_streaming.2Fencoding) apparently supports MMS streaming, and also has API binding to various languages, including C#.

w:[Real Time Streaming Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Streaming_Protocol) lists some server implementations that supports Real Time Streaming Protocol.